# Unable to playback .mp4 audio file in Firefox, works in Chrome

Tags: html, firefox, ffmpeg, mp4, mp4a

I have been trying to play a file through Firefox to see if it is compatible for a website and cannot figure out why it cannot play whereas it will play on Chrome okay. It simply shows a error box that the "video cannot be played because the file is corrupt". I've trawled through information on .mp4 files and Firefox's supported codec types but have not found much aside from recent posts on how FF should be able to play this content in 2015. Here is a ffprobe of the file.

`Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'two.mp4':
Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: M4A mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2015-08-06 08:17:05
    encoder         : Nero AAC codec / 1.5.4.0
    Duration        : 00:03:28.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 131 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0    : start 0.027333, end 208.768000
    Metadata:
      title           :
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 96000 Hz, stereo, flt p, 128 kb/s (default)`

Any reason why this local file wouldn't play through FF on Windows 41.0.2?

Comment: So it is only audio? You should always show the complete `ffprobe` output. Did you make the file? If yes, provide details of how you made it. Please provide a link to the file.

Comment: Yes audio only, Stream0:0. What is shown is the complete output for ffprobe unless you are meaning the version info of ffprobe as well. I did not make the file and do not have the details for it. I realise having somebody take a look at the file would be the easiest way, I don't own the file and would need permission to upload it anywhere.

Comment: It appears that such files with an audio rate of 96000 Hz are unsupported by your Firefox. I don't know why, and I did not search any documentation. A lame workaround is to resample to to an audio rate of 48000 or lower for full support.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Prior to posting I did scrounge for info on whether the sample rate had any effect but came up with very little. Did you simply encode a file with the same settings to test this? I should have probably thought to do that to test FF 41.0.2 outright. Looks like I will have to look at using Flash to play this back.

Comment: I simply made test files of various audio rates supported by the FFmpeg encoder `aac`, as shown by `ffmpeg -h encoder=aac`, and then tested Firefox in a Windows VM using HTML5 `<video>` element.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that sample rates above 48000 are not natively supported by Firefox 41.0.2 in  elements.